# Underscore.js, set the current date to keys containing past dates

Tags: javascript, json, date, underscore.js

I've a large array (JSON coming from a server request) and inside this array I've lots of JSON objects. One of the keys contains a date in ISO format. I would like to change the value of this key, so that if the date is past or equals today, all the keys containing a past or current date changes its value to the current date (today), while the future (and the current) dates stay the same.

So, for example, here:

```
({
 "date_upd": "2015-02-05T19:11:56.520Z"
 },
{
 "date_upd": "2015-03-08T19:12:56.520Z"
 },
{
 "date_upd": "2015-02-05T19:11:56.520Z"
 })
```

The first two keys should change to 2015-04-08.

Is this possible with underscore?

Comment: That's neither JSON nor even valid javascript code

Comment: @hindmost edited, sorry

Comment: look at _.map, which should enable you to run a transformation on all the elements.

Comment: @doldt I looked at it before posting, but I could not find a way to make it work as I would

Comment: @3000 show us the code you tried, we'll try to help in fixing it.

Comment: @doldt The problem is I couln't find a way to return the entire object, only a basic array derived from the function iteratee. I need the entire object (it has many keys), not only an array of values

Comment: @3000 We can't help you if you don't post some code.

Comment: _.map(JSONArray, function(){ JSONArray.date_upd<new Date().toISOString() ? new Date().toISOString() : JSONArray.date_upd });

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var today = new Date().toISOString();
_.each(your_array, function(item){
    item.date_upd = item.date_upd < today ? today : item.date_upd;
});
```

`your_array` will be updated in place. So after the each call completes, the changes should be reflected in `your_array`.